# gluPerspective with SFML: same compilation, different results. Graphics not showing

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am using SFML library (C++) and I copy-pasted Laurent Gomila's example (http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-opengl.php) to test OpenGL.

It worked well. But at some point I would start playing with some of the gl functions... When I changed the first paramether of this...:

```
gluPerspective(100.f, 1.f, 0.1f, 500.f);
```

I could notice some diferences when I executed the program, but the 3rd or 4th time I changedThatParameter+compiled, it stopped displaying the graphics. I backtracked to get them displayed again but... guess what? THEY DIDN'T! Same code as before, but still not graphics!

What could possibly be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being that my noobness got my RAM in trouble because I was stacking memory allocations without freeing none of them.

After implementing proper deletion of memory assignment it worked as it should have.